# Copy a pivot table into a regular table

Tags: excel, copy, pivot

I have a pivot table. I would like to copy the data in it to a new sheet and to copy only the content without any formulas behind. As if it was an ordinary table (like copy special). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: OK. How can I recognize the special copy? and how to copy it with its format?

Comment: How can I choose the special copy and in order  copy it with its format?